# Serving express static files issue

Tags: node.js, express, static

I am having issues w/ serving static files in my current Express app, although I've done a similar setup in a bunch of other apps.. My folder structure is as follows:

```
/rootfolder/
    /app
        package.json
        /client
            /dist
                /static
                index.html

        /server
            /src
                index.js
```

Relevant part of my `server/src/index.js`:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "dist")));`

Where `__dirname = /rootfolder/app/server/src`

And when the user hits the `/` endpoint:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(appRoot.path + "/client/dist/index.html");
});
```

Where `appRoot.path = /rootfolder/app`

When I hit the `/` endpoint, I get a status 200 with the following text:

`/rootfolder/app/client/dist/index.html`

From what I can tell, the files are coded relative to each other correctly.. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if I understand this correctly, you cannot access your static files?

Comment: Yes, correct @AmirHosseinRd

Comment: if either my answer or @Kano answer is correct , as courtesy can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Yep, will accept once i get this locked down lol @AmirHosseinRd

Comment: Sure,feel free to ask if u came across any errors

Comment: @AmirHosseinRd @Kano I am now using `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "dist")));` and it appears my `index.html` file is able to load. However, files in the `static` folder are still returning `404` :(

Comment: well that is because you are telling your app to use dist as the main directory to load static files so if you have some files you wanna access in static directory, make sure you use /static before your file name. For instance  /static/image1.jpg

Comment: Yeah, I think i'm already doing that. Heres an example: `http://localhost:3000/static/css/app.4c46ca4f5387691e80b6de07b50c4d94.css`

Comment: You can't do it that way. Please take a look at my edit for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'client','dist')));
```

It basically gets the root directory and combines it with /client+ /dist + /static to give you the full route, without being relative path.

Now Let's call rootdirectory/client/dist X. That is the main directory for static files
If you have other files that are static but not in the same folder, you will have to give relative path from the X directory 
Example:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.sendFile('/static/data.txt');
}
```

In the example above you indicate that the static file(data.txt) is located in the X/static directory. 
Therefore => rootDirectory/client/dist/static/data.txt

2nd Example: 
Let's say you have a folder in dist called images which you want to only store images. 
when you are giving routes, you MUST use /images/filename.extention

Comment: Hi - I tried that and it's giving me a bunch of `404` errors on my static files. I think it's because my `index.html` is in my `dist` folder, not `static`..

Comment: in that case, use the same command without  'static' or move the file into static folder

Answer (score 0):

You're using `res.send()` instead of [`res.sendFile()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile)

Also I suggest resolving your path via the `path` module, instead of concatenating a string.

```
const path = require('path')

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'dist', 'static')))
```

And for the response of `/`:

`res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'dist', 'index.html')))`

Comment: HI - that gives me `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/rootfolder/app/server/src/routes/main/client/dist/index.html'`

Comment: Then fix your path :) Something like `path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', '..', 'client', 'dist', 'static')` should do it. But I'm not sure why you're setting global static files for your express app in `app/server/src/routes/main`? Usually that sort of thing is handled in your main Express file, which usually resides in `app/server` simply. But that's up to you and a per-project thing, I imagine.

Comment: I moved the `sendFile` method to my `app/server/index.js` file as shown above

Comment: I also updated my question to reflect my current code

Comment: You're still concatenating a string when serving the index.html file. Replace that with: `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'client', 'dist', 'index.html'))` and let me know what you get back when you request `/`